# JavaScript regx only on plus sign

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I would like to be able to remove the + sign from an empty number or string, i.e. if I have +44566677 do noting but if I have + then set the const or data as null. So looking for an easy regx that can tell the string just has +

Comment: you know the drill, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: you might need to escape the `+` character with `\+` in your regex

Comment: `^\+$` match start, a plus sign, end

Comment: Wouldn't simple check against "+" be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple regex that matches the start of a string, then a single plus sign, then the end of a string - so the plus sign is the only character in the string:

```js
const str1 = "+";
const str2 = "+ 44566677";
const regex = /^\+$/;
console.log(regex.test(str1));
console.log(regex.test(str2));
```